# Protractor not able to find element in Overlay

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to get text of an error message using protractor-typescript. The message appears for few seconds only.

below is the complete HTML of the element:

```
<mas-popup-message _ngcontent-c24="" _nghost-c6="" class="ng-star-inserted">
<div _ngcontent-c6="" class="report-panel__container">
  <i _ngcontent-c6="" class="material-icons close">close</i>

  <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="report-panel__container-columns ng-star-inserted">
  <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="report-panel__container-columns-content-error">User Creation Failed</div>
  </div>
    <!---->
    <!---->

</div>
</mas-popup-message>
```

i have tried below code

```
  browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.tagName("mas-popup-message"))),5000,"error returned");
```

i have used isDisplayed(), isPresent(), EC.presenceOf but it is returning same error in each case.

NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator:

locators which i am using is correct. I think the element is in overlay but it is not an iframe. Can anyone help what can be the possible solution?

Comment: Hey. First, can you what's is changing when the error appears for a few is displayed (normally either class of some element gets appended with `show`, `display` or anything like that; OR the element appears and goes away after that). And second take a look what happens with the error message after it disappears (most likely it still can be accessed from the browser's console). Let me know the results and I'll help you

Comment: The complete HTML code which I shared in question above appears when the error message is displayed and disappears when the error message disappears

Comment: Then I would try to wait for presence of `$('.report-panel__container-columns-content-error')` and then instead of `.getText()` use `.getAttribute("innerText");` let me know if you need help with writing the exact solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:
  `browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css("mas-popup-message"))),5000,"error returned");`